# Logo link not clickable on Wordpress Site

Tags: html, css, wordpress, z-index

I have a small issue, I have a wordpress site and the logo has a link with the homepage URL (should be standard across all websites). However, the logo is not clickable until some other links has been clicked on.

When you first go into the site without clicking on anything, the logo is not clickable. However, when you click on "About" on the menu, the logo is then clickable. Apparently the z-index is not the issue as I tried to give a very high z-index to the  tag.

http://urlgone.com/019fdf/

I will appreciate your guidance to resolve this issue. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just check your problem. This is a quick fix for your issue. Please used this code snippets. In your custom.css file in theme.

```
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your speedy answer to my query. I have pasted your code into to css and it really works. However, when the browser is shrinked to a mobile display (responsive site), the menu is kinda screwed up. You can try shrinking your browser and you will see the weird menu.

Comment: :) Sorry my bad. Just remove  'display: inline-block !important;'. Then every thing okay.

Comment: It's okay. I have fixed that, just did @media css to fix that for different screen sizes. Thanks so much!

Comment: That's true. But don't go that much. As I mention in previous comment. Just remove  'display: inline-block !important;'.

Comment: Yup, tried your method and it works too so I have reverted back to your solution. Thanks! Have a nice day ahead!